# Sublime text Problems

Tags: python

I am beginner in programming. I have just started to learn Python and  have recently install 3.7 on my mac. After that I tried to simple code such as print(18 / 4) and answer should be like this 4.5 if I use // then would be 4. I assumed that might be an installation problem. but when I reinstall the editor it seems same. To make sure that I am right or wrong in this case, I did use online editor from official python website, it seems ok (4.5). It may be not a huge problem but I want to make myself clear from beginning. Just need a quick solution! Thanks.

Comment: what is the sublime text role in your problem? we need some code or screen shot and more detail of your issue

Comment: @Mohammadb sublime text {print( 18 / 4 )= 4
but it should be 4.5 because I didn't write" // " rather than /. I tried to figure this out over python official website with online editor and it seems 4.5 is ok. i hope it will work.

Comment: Is it possible that SublimeText defaults to the system's Python that afaik is v.2.7?  In this case the interpreter defaults to integer division, hence `18/4` → `4`.  And you ask, what I want to do? You have to notify SublimeText that you want to use v. 3.x but I don't know the exact procedure, and this is why this is a comment and not an answer...

Comment: How is Sublime Text related to this issue? It sounds like this is just a Python issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, Python does not depend on what editor you are using. You can use any editor to begin with.

From https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/introduction.html

```
Division (/) always returns a float. 
To do floor division and get an integer result (discarding any fractional result) 
you can use the // operator; to calculate the remainder you can use %
```

So 18/4 gives you 4.5, a float result.
But 18//4 gives you 4, a integer result, since it gets rid of the fractional result.

Comment: Exactly but it seems when I write 18/4 it gives me 4 but why? I should get 4.5 instead of  4 because I didn't use //

Comment: Use python interpreter to start learning python (Just open python3.7 command line prompt) to learn. Don't use python interpreter of a text editor. Instead use it to write code, and use command line to run the code like ```python test.py```

Answer (score 0):

`"/"` Divide left operand by the right one **(always results into float)**

```
5/2=2.5
```

`"//"` Floor division - division that results into whole number adjusted to the left in the number line, divide left operand by the right one **(always result into int)**

```
5//2=2
```